# Color only header with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, header, styles

Is there a way to give a colour to the header of a dataframe column with pandas?

What I have now is:

def funct(x):

```
c1 = 'background-color: #add8e6'
df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns = x.columns)
df1['Sales in pieces last 6 weeks'] = c1
return df1
```

sales_report.style.apply(funct,axis = None).to_excel(writer)

So, in short, I have the data frame sales_report. I want the header of the column 'Sales in pieces last 6 weeks' to have a background color. Now, the whole column without the header has that background color.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do that with the css class `row_heading`.

(See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#CSS-classes)

---

Another option would be:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns = x.columns)

df1.style.set_table_styles(
   [{
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [('background-color', '#add8e6')]
   }])
```

Comment: how can I get the styled dataframe into excel?